# Remove empty strings from a tuple RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tuples, rdd

I have a RDD of the form `(name,[token1, token2, ...])` with `name` being the key and `token` being the values. For example: `(Robert,['hello', 'movie', '', 'cinema'])` and I would like to remove the empty strings in the values using `map`.

My attempt was:

```
new_tuple = tuple.map(lambda x: (x[0], [s for s in x[1] if len(s)>0]))
```

to obtain `(Robert,['hello', 'movie', 'cinema'])`

But I feel like there is a less redundant way of doing it?

After that, I want to remove items that might end up without any values (tokens) after my above operation, would the following work?:

```
final_tuple = new_tuple.filter(lambda x: len(x[1])>0)
```

Comment: better `[s for s in x[1] if s]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:
`a = (Robert,['hello', 'movie', '', 'cinema'])`

then `a = (a[0], list(filter(None, a[1])))`

## This is the best way to remove None, False, 0, "", '' from sequence

Comment: in python3 filter will return filter object, so the end result will be `('Robert', <filter object at 0xmemoryaddress>)`. You need to apply also list(), e.g. `a = (a[0], list(filter(None, a[1])))` to get the desired result.